# leaderkey binding errors in Mingw64 (git bash)

Tags: key-bindings

Learning Vim and love it.

I’m having challenges getting the below leaderkey to work in my git bash instance of Vim.

I want to:

- while in normal mode I want to insert new line under the current line
- Go to beginning of that line
- Insert the `-` character
- Tab and remain in insert mode

I understand the below should do that but it does everything except the `-` piece.

```
nnoremap <leader>o o<esc>0i-^I
```

A contributor provided guidance to use, however this does not work either. It will:

- insert a new line below the word
- go to the beginning of the line in normal mode
- tab the line and leave in insert mode

however it is *not* insert the character "-"

```
nnoremap <leader>o o<Esc>0i-<Tab>
```

Any thoughts? This works in my popOS distribution but not in my gitbash (on windows computer that runs mingw64

vim --version output below

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Feb 11 2023 19:56:29)
Included patches: 1-1302
Compiled by <https://www.msys2.org/>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl/dyn          +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3/dyn       +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim90"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/include/ncursesw -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc -pipe -Wl,--as-needed -o vim.exe -lm -lncursesw -liconv -lacl -lintl -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
```

however if I run vim --clean the mapping **does** work.

As far as I can tell I don't have any unique mappings to my tab key.

Comment: It seems to me that we miss something *the below* (a keybinding ?) seems to be missing.

Comment: Agree with Vivian. Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: Please [edit] to include missing context and details.

Comment: apologies! added  in the missing context

Comment: I would do `nnoremap <leader>o o<Esc>0i-<Tab>`

Comment: Hi -- I still have the same issue. It isn't printing the "-" but its doing everything else. Note this appears unique to mingw64 (mysys2)implementation of bash
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Feb 11 2023 19:56:29)

Comment: Thanks for improving your question. We're waiting for some votes to reopen. In the mean time, please edit and add the output of `vim --version`. Do you have any mappings defined for `<Tab>`? Do the configs of your Vims differ? Does it work with `vim --clean`?

Comment: [Please don’t post pictures of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: The `--clean` flag drop the plugins. What if you type the sequence in normal mode? To find the culprit plugin you could disable some to step by step find the one that cause the problem. `<Tab>` is very often use to trigger completion or to trigger snippet I would start with these.

Comment: Running `:map <Tab>` might also give some insights.